# solr rpm for centOS

Tags: solr

Does any know if there is Solr RPM for centOS? I am working on a project, which is not allowed to download any software without RPM.

If the answer is NOT, then I am wondering why there is no Solr RPM. Solr is so popular, and would that be easy to have a RPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, there are a few Fedora flavour Solr 4 and 5 versions out there: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=solr

Unfortunately, there is still no version 6.

For the daring and adventurous, you can build your own RPM, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-rpm1/